# The best way to connect on MySQL from Android?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I want to access and replicate data between an Android app and MySQL server (both ways).

I will create a local db and a db on MySQL server.

When internet connection is enabled I will verify the db version, transfer some data to MySQL server, process there requests and get the latest database version on mobile device.

For the moment I found a JSON solution ( http://itweb-projects.com/wordpress/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php ), but I don't know if it's the best solution. What you think?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't access the MySQL database directly from you android app. I'd access it through some sort of REST API. This immediately brings to mind the the [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) class and this [great video from GoogleIO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).

Comment: I studied the SyncAdapter app, but it's more than i need. I like to keep things simple.

Comment: Yes, it is a lot. You don't have to use the full blown thing though. You can just make your own simple REST stuff. I was just trying to give an example.